# Would working on a large project vs making a small app for a company make your resume looks better?

Tags: resume

so my company is contracting government's jobs. Recently, our consumer site has nothing much going on, so I was transferred back to own office to develop an e-claim mobile app for internal employees to use. My team would probably have two developers including me, and a tech lead, that's all. Needless to say it is a rather small project, and I may need to shift out again depending on customer's requirement. However I am happy that I can work on something new, and pick up new technologies along the way (I have never done mobile apps before). But would working on a small project for my company that does not generate revenue look good on my resume?

Comment: Focus on learning the technology for now. Your first app won't be groundbreaking anyway. In any case, you're asking for our opinions. This site doesn't deal well with opinion-based questions. This question will get closed unless you can make the question more concrete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But would working on a small project for my company that does not generate revenue look good on my resume?

As a developer, future employers are unlikely to care about the size of the project you worked on, whether it was internal or external, or whether it was revenue generating. All of those points are someone else's job.

Instead, they care what experience you gained from it, how you ensured you did a good job, what tools / libraries / languages / frameworks you used to build it, whether you held that job down for a reasonable period of time (didn't keep job hopping every few months), etc. If your resume shows all of that, then this experience is an asset.

There are of course some exceptions. If you worked on a successful, high flying project that they'll almost certainly have heard of, that's a great plus. Or if you've clearly been in a position of responsibility over a well-known project that failed (security developer for a project that had a massive data leak for instance), that's obviously not good. But "I worked on a small project that you haven't heard of successfully for a while" - not an issue whatsoever.

Comment: Agree, project target is not critical, your technology control / knowledge would be in question during the new job search